# Getting incorrect output from the flax model's init call

Tags: jax, flax

I am trying to create a simple neural network using flax, as shown below.

However, the `params` frozen dict I receive as the output to of `model.init` is empty instead of having the parameters of the neural network. Also the the `type(predictions)` is `flax.linen.combinators.Sequential` object instead of being a `DeviceArray`.

Can someone help me understand what is wrong with this code snippet?

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import flax.linen as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class MLP(nn.Module):
    @nn.compact
    def __call__(self, x):
        return nn.Sequential(
            [
                nn.Dense(40),
                nn.relu,
                nn.Dense(40),
                nn.Dense(1),
            ]
        )


model = MLP()
dummy_input = jnp.ones((40, 40, 1))
params = model.init(jax.random.PRNGKey(0), dummy_input)
jax.tree_util.tree_map(lambda x: x.shape, params)

n = 100
x_inputs = jnp.linspace(-10, 10, n).reshape(1, -1)
y_targets = jnp.sin(x_inputs)
predictions = model.apply(params, x_inputs)

plt.plot(x_inputs.reshape(-1), y_targets.reshape(-1))
plt.plot(x_inputs.reshape(-1), predictions.reshape(-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `nn.Sequential` returns a function that needs to be called with input. Replacing

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
    @nn.compact
    def __call__(self, x):
        return nn.Sequential(
            [
                nn.Dense(40),
                nn.relu,
                nn.Dense(40),
                nn.Dense(1),
            ]
        )
```

with

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
    @nn.compact
    def __call__(self, x):
        return nn.Sequential(
            [
                nn.Dense(40),
                nn.relu,
                nn.Dense(40),
                nn.Dense(1),
            ]
        )(x)
```

Solves the problem.